# Codeigniter v 3.0.6 sin index.php

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-3

Saludos desarrolladores, estoy 3 dias dando vueltas en como quitar el index.php de codeigniter 3, desintale y volvi a instalar el xampp, Edite el archivo de configuracion de apache, httpd.conf, editando los valores de AllowOverride de none a all. Si tmb edite el config.php de index page. En codeigniter 2 tengo el problema solucionado. pero en la version 3.0.6 no desaparece el index php.

He probado con varios archivos .htaccess con diferentes configuraciones.

Agradeceria si me pudieran facilitar la descarga del archivo zip de codeigniter en blanco (sin el index.php) en la version 3 que este operativo. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, comparte los intentos que hiciste con .htaccess, pueden servirle de orientación a algún usuario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente CodeIgniter se encuentra en la versión 3.1.0 y su código fuente original lo puedes descargar desde su página oficial [Descargar CodeIgniter oficial](https://codeigniter.com/download). Te recomendaría que bajes una nueva versión más limpia e instales tu proyecto nuevamente, o si recuerdas todos los cambios que hiciste en la configuración del framework.

La respuesta que necesitas la puedes encontrar aquí: [Eliminar index.php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22102/no-puedo-eliminar-el-index-php-en-la-url-en-code-igniter/24727#24727)

Comment: Por políticas de StackExchange no deberíamos repetir preguntas, dado que pueden marcarlas como spam o demás. Las preguntas y sus respuestas hasta donde se, no dejan de funcionar así sin más, sino cuando están reportadas :)

¿Te funcionó la solución?

Comment: Perdon pense que era de SO no de SOes ya vi mi error