# No puedo eliminar el index.php en la URL en CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess

Saludos

Sigo este [curso](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUskO1brWhI). Aquí enseñan como eliminar (o más bien ocultar) el index.php en las URL's de CodeIgniter configurando un archivo `.htaccess` en la raíz de la aplicación, lo cual no me funcionó y me gustaría saber por qué.

Aquí está mi repositorio:

https://github.com/ashcrimson/CodeIgniter/tree/master/CodeIgniter

Y aquí mi .htaccess:

http://pastebin.com/eCU5UgL0

Comment: Tienes habilitado el modulo `mod_rewrite` en apache?

Comment: Que versión de PHP usas?

Comment: Si la respuesta solucionó tu duda, ¿puedes aceptarla?

Answer (score 2):

Primero se debe modificar el archivo "CodeIgniter/application/config/config.php"(Según veo ya lo hiciste, pero lo indico por si a alguien más le sirve esta respuesta) teniendo en cuenta que ahora debe quedar así:

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Además del paso anterior, en un proyecto que realicé con CodeIgniter 2.0 utilicé el siguiente código en un .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Lo probé recientemente en CodeIgniter 3.0 y sigue funcionando. La versión de php que utilizo es 5.6.19 y tengo activo el módulo de redireccionamiento (mod_rewrite) en mi servidor Apache

Comment: ¿Te funcionó esta respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Estoy seguro que este código te servirá:

```
    #Activamos la reescritura SI SOLO SI el mod_rewrite se encuentra activado, así se evitan errores 500
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Suponiendo que el listado de directorios esté desactivado, permitimos indexación y activamos el rewrite
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on

    # Usualmente "AllowOverride" debería estar en 'All' en el apache.conf/vhost.conf, pero si no descomentas lo siguiente para evitar un error 404
    #AllowOverride All

    # Se supone que la regla aplica desde el directorio donde se encuentra el .htaccess pero si es necesario lo especificas, siendo / la raiz de dominio
    #RewriteBase /

    # con esta instrucción bloqueamos el acceso a la carpeta system, si es que se encuentra en el directorio web
    RedirectMatch 403 ^/(system).*$

    # Antes de redireccionar, se verifica que la petición no sea a un directorio o archivo existente
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Si el archivo/directorio no existe, redireccionamos
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Si tu versión PHP és 5.2.6 o superior:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Si tu versión PHP és 5.2.5 o inferior:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Incluso con esto puede ser que no te funcione, entonces prueba con éste código:

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://**tuWeb**.es/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://**tuWeb**.es/ [R=301,L]
```

[.htacces](/questions/tagged/.htacces)[codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter)[php](/questions/tagged/php)

Comment: Tengo PHP 7, tengo mod_rewrite activado en httpd.conf y proé con todos los códigos posibles que posteaste en mi .htaccess y ninguno funcionó. Incluso probé con uno que sale en este video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbYCGSe7HZ0

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Pero sigo sin poder eliminar el index.php de las urls.

Answer (score 0):

Hola he tenido el mismo problema pero de tanto dar con todo eso, di con la solución; mi directorio tiene la primera letra mayúscula es decir: www/Kyrstalos/ y en la línea en .htaccess la tenía así:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Krystalos/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Y me daba error una y otra vez, lo que hice fue colocar todo en minúsculas y wualaaaa, entonces quedó así:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /krystalos/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Resueltos todos los problemas...

Aquí está mi .htaccess por si te sirve de algo:

```
# Suponiendo que el listado de directorios esté desactivado, permitimos indexación y activamos el rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Usualmente "AllowOverride" debería estar en 'All' en el apache.conf/vhost.conf, pero si no descomentas lo siguiente para evitar un error 404
#AllowOverride All

# Se supone que la regla aplica desde el directorio donde se encuentra el .htaccess pero si es necesario lo especificas, siendo / la raiz de dominio
#RewriteBase /

# con esta instrucción bloqueamos el acceso a la carpeta system, si es que se encuentra en el directorio web
RedirectMatch 403 ^/(system).*$

# Antes de redireccionar, se verifica que la petición no sea a un directorio o archivo existente
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Si el archivo/directorio no existe, redireccionamos
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /krystalos/index.php/$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /krystalos/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu código, pues una respuesta conteniendo sólo código se considera de baja calidad