# ¿Porque la ruta del controlador por defecto no funciona?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con CodeIgniter. Cuando un usuario visita mi pagina, deseo que al poner la dirección (en este caso lo estoy probando en el localhost) del sitio se acceda a la pagina home.php.

Entiendo que para lograr esto, la ruta `$route['default_controller']` tiene que apuntar a algun controlador en donde renderize la vista que necesito.

Pues bien, alli esta mi problema. No sucede. Mi ruta se mira asi:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/index';
```

Mi controlador se mira asi:

```
<?php

  class Pages extends CI_Controller{

    public function index()
    {
      $this->load->view('frontend/templates/header');
      $this->load->view('pages/home');
      $this->load->view('frontend/templates/footer');
    }
}
```

Y por supuesto que tengo las vistas correspondientes en `views/pages/home.php` y `views/frontend/templates/header.php` y `footer.php`.

Modifique un poco el .htaccess de la carpeta raiz para que se vea asi:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Pero cuando voy a la ruta raíz de mi proyecto, simplemente me aparece una pagina en blanco. Todas las demás rutas y funcionalidades funcionan perfectamente. ¿Alguien tiene una idea?

Comment: Probaste colocando `$route['default_controller'] = 'pages';`? al poner solo el nombre de tu controlador te dirige automaticamente a la funcion index.

Comment: @JuanPinzón si, la verdad que ese fue mi primer intento, pero al ver que no funcionaba, especifique la funcion index.

Comment: En los logs de tu servidor, no obtienes ningun error?

Comment: @JuanPinzón Pues no, la verdad es que no. Revise en /opt/lampp/logs en access_log, error_log y php_error_log y no hay nada referente a esto, de hecho nisiquiera hay logs del dia de hoy.

Comment: Y si ingresas a `http://localhost/tu_proyecto/index.php/pages` si obtienes las vistas que estas cargando en la funcion index?

Comment: @JuanPinzón pues lo acabo de probar y no dio. Pero! acabo de poner localhost/mi_proyecto/index.php y si dio. No soy experto en esto, pero pense que las reglas de redireccion en el .htaccess eran para evitar el index.php en la direccion inicial. Alguna idea?

Comment: Entonces el problema esta en tu htacces, revisa las reglas que tienes ahi, esta pregunta te puede servir https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22102/no-puedo-eliminar-el-index-php-en-la-url-en-code-igniter/24727#24727

Comment: Tu problema esta en el **.htaccess** con los cambios que hiciste y si no hubieras tocado éste fichero, con http://localhost/tu_proyecto te carga la vista que quieres

Comment: @JuanPinzón fui a la [wiki oficial de Codeigniter y segui todos los pasos que alli se describen](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Removing-index.php-from-a-URL-path-in-XAMPP-for-Windows). Todo sigue igual. Lo curioso es que cuando pongo localhost/mi_proyecto/index.php si funciona, pero si pongo localhost/mi_proyecto/ no funciona. Siento como que no se esta llamando al controlador cuando esta vacia esa parte. Alguna otra idea?

Comment: Algunas veces el htacces que se pone en la documentación oficial de codeigniter no funciona, a continuacion te dejo algunos htaccess que puedes probar, https://github.com/pinzon1992/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: @JuanPinzón gracias, los probare.

Comment: tienes activado el rewritte de tu servidor?

Comment: @JuanPinzón gracias por tu ayuda. No se porque, pero no funciona nada. Copie todas las carpetas a un nuevo proyecto de codeigniter y si funciono, sin cambiar nada. No entiendo que paso, pero asi lo solucione. Gracias por la ayuda.